# Excel imported data can`t be correctly converted into chart

Tags: excel, charts, import

I am using Office 365.

When I import data via the text import wizard and want to plot the data afterwards the chart name, X axis and X axis are completly messed up.
If I plot the data the chart title is filled with: 1st the "name" cell(good), 2nd with a dozen of values of the X **and** Y axsis (red).
The Y axsis is right below the chart title (blue).
The X axsis is completly missing (shoud be violet).
[See here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcFiC.png)

I formated it correctly during the import. So the problem isn`t there.
I cannot move the informations areas (red, blue [violet]). They are static( except in their row).

If I type in the values per hand everithing works fine.

Hope somebody can help me untill tomorrow. Would be realy nice of you. 
Thank you very much and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uus this macro. Because your data is string, Error occur.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, rngDB As Range
    Set rngDB = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    vDB = rngDB
    rngDB.NumberFormat = "General"
    rngDB = vDB
End Sub
```